# Limit in group by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a tasks table that I'm querying and trying to group the result by due date and also limit the number of tasks returned per group to 10.

```
     id    |     name         | duedate
---------------------------------------------
    101    |      task1       | 2015-03-05
    102    |      task2       |
    104    |      task3       | 2015-03-06
    105    |      task4       | 2015-03-07
    106    |      task5       | 
    107    |      task6       | 2015-02-28
    108    |      task7       | 2015-02-27
    109    |      task8       | 2015-02-05
    111    |      task9       |
```

I'm trying to group the tasks into 4 groups and limit each group to 10 tasks:

1. Duedate = today
2. Duedate = today - 7days
3. Duedate = today + 7days
4. Duedate = null

I'm using the postgres window function to achieve this. The problem is that I can't manage to use "partition by" for the groups.

So far I have managed to come up with this:

```
select * from ( select id,name,duedate,row_number()  
  OVER (PARTITION BY duedate order by duedate)  as rownum from tasks
  ) tmp where rownum < 10;
```

This won't work because it creates a group for every duedate.

Is it possible without using multiple queries ?

Comment: What "multiple queries"?  You only have one query in your question.

Comment: By multiple queries I mean without window function. Just 4 regular selects for each group condition.

Comment: Is your intent to have the groups represent exact dates, or ranges? Should the group for `Duedate = today - 7days` only be the specific date one week ago, or all dates within the range today - 7 days?

Comment: It should be all dates in the range today - 7 days. I need to get all the tasks that have duedate in the last 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression in the `partition by`:

```
select *
from (select id, name, duedate,
             row_number()  over (partition by (case when duedate = CURRENT_DATE then 1
                                                    when duedate >= CURRENT_DATE - interval '7 day' and duedate < CURRENT_DATE then 2
                                                    when duedate <= CURRENT_DATE + interval '7 day' and duedate > CURRENT_DATE then 3
                                               end)
                                 order by duedate) as rownum
      from tasks
      where duedate >= CURRENT_DATE - interval '7 day' and
            duedate <= CURRENT_DATE + interval '7 day'
     ) tmp
where rownum < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to form four groups that represent

1. today
2. items between one week ago and today (excluding today)
3. items within one week from today (excluding today)
4. missing duedate

and disregard all other dates then maybe something like this would work:

```
select *,
  -- I left the case expression in to show what it does.
  case 
    when Duedate = current_date 
    then 1
    when Duedate >= current_date - interval '7 days' 
     and Duedate < current_date 
    then 2
    when Duedate <= current_date + interval '7 days' 
     and Duedate > current_date 
    then 3
  end as grouping
from ( 
  select 
    id,
    name,
    duedate,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY 
      case 
        when Duedate = current_date then 1
        when Duedate >= current_date - interval '7 days' 
                       and Duedate < current_date 
                       then 2
        when Duedate <= current_date + interval '7 days' 
                       and Duedate > current_date 
                       then 3
      end 
      order by duedate
  ) as rownum 
  from tasks
  where (Duedate >= current_date - interval '7 days'
    and Duedate <= current_date + interval '7 days') 
     or Duedate is null

) tmp where rownum < 10;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae88b/3) (with slightly modified dates to get some results)

This would produce a result similar to this:

```
|  id |   name |                 duedate | rownum | grouping |
|-----|--------|-------------------------|--------|----------|
| 112 | task10 | April, 04 2015 00:00:00 |      1 |        1 |
| 113 | task11 | April, 04 2015 00:00:00 |      2 |        1 |
| 107 |  task6 | March, 28 2015 00:00:00 |      1 |        2 |
| 108 |  task7 | March, 29 2015 00:00:00 |      2 |        2 |
| 104 |  task3 | April, 06 2015 00:00:00 |      1 |        3 |
| 105 |  task4 | April, 07 2015 00:00:00 |      2 |        3 |
| 101 |  task1 | April, 11 2015 00:00:00 |      3 |        3 |
| 102 |  task2 |                  (null) |      1 |   (null) |
| 106 |  task5 |                  (null) |      2 |   (null) |
| 111 |  task9 |                  (null) |      3 |   (null) |
```